# Unable to insert in table using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm using hibernate to create table and then i'm inserting the records in the table when application starts.

For inserting the record i'm using the last example of [this](https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-web-application-part-3-spring-data-jpa/) page

**Problem :** Hibernate is able to create the tables but when i'm inserting the records at the application startup it is not getting inserted.

On the other hand if i use a REST service to do the same task it works perfectly fine.

Here is my JPA class.

```
package com.vizexperts.georbis.usermanagement.types;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class TestMe {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long Id;

    @Column
    String name;

    public TestMe(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Here is corresponding `TestMeRepository` class.

```
package com.vizexperts.georbis.usermanagement.types;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface TestMeRepository extends CrudRepository<TestMe, Long> {
    TestMe findByName(String name);
}
```

And this is how i'm inserting the data.

```
package com.vizexperts.georbis.config;
import com.vizexperts.georbis.usermanagement.types.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
public class InitialDataConfig  implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>{
    @Autowired
    TestMeRepository testMeRepository;
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
         // Here newly saved object is returned as testMe
         // when debugging i can see the auto generated **id** for 
         // testMe object.
         TestMe testMe = testMeRepository.save(new TestMe("Test"));
    }
}
```

And as i said if i use the following service it works.

```
@RequestMapping("/georbis/test")
    public Response<Void> test(){
        testMeRepository.save(new TestMe("working"));
        return new Response<>(true, "working");
    }
```

Comment: Any error/exception on start ?

Comment: Use `CommandLineRunner` instead.

Comment: @VinayVeluri no error/exception at all. method executes successfully. Even  ``save``  method returns ``testMe`` object where i can see the newly saved object with auto generated ``id``.

Comment: @SanjayRawat same is the case with ``CommandLineRunner``  everything executes but nothing shows up in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that you are missing `@Component` annotation on your `InitialDataConfig` class.

And that is why this class is not registered as a bean and `onApplicationEvent` method is never called.

Add the `@Component` annotation and it should work fine.

Alternately you can use `CommandLineRunner`, try this [example](https://github.com/RawSanj/SOFRepos/blob/master/SpringDataDemo/src/main/java/com/rawsanj/springdata/SpringDataDemoApplication.java).

Comment: I have used ``@Component`` annotation just forgot to update the question.
Still nothing is getting inserted in the table.

Comment: Actually this is how i used the ``CommandLineRunner``
http://nixmash.com/java/using-spring-boot-commandlinerunner/

Comment: Also ``onApplicationEvent`` and ``run`` method in case of ``CommandLineRunner`` both are getting called.

Comment: Well that's strange, can you share the code in github or any other site? I will try and figure out the issue, coz what you are doing seems fine.

Comment: Well i created a separate project so that i can send you the code and guess what it is working in new project but not in older one.